# my datastax cluster nodetool ring shows duplicate token

Tags: cassandra, datastax, nodetool, datastax-startup

My datastax cluster nodetool ring shows duplicate token(8814750030873335965), one of these has an empty address. I don't know why or how to fix this.

Please see the result below:

```
[root@iZ11yj300zkZ ~]# nodetool ring

Datacenter: Analytics
=====================
Address        Rack    Status State   Load       Owns  Token
                                                       8814750030873335965
10.47.183.XXX  rack1   Up     Normal  28.53 GB   ?     -7618874366231544036
10.47.183.XXX  rack1   Up     Normal  32.48 GB   ?     -4185904510783898313
10.47.183.XX   rack1   Up     Normal  24.66 GB   ?     -1642199767888853934
10.47.183.XXX rack1   Up     Normal  32.07 GB   ?     -250600750751986775
10.47.183.XXX   rack1   Up     Normal  215.28 KB  ?     8814750030873335965

Datacenter: Solr
==========
Address        Rack   Status State   Load      Owns    Token

10.47.182.1XX  rack1  Up     Normal  26.16 GB  ?       6773516272242009347
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a duplicate token, that's just the last token in the ring. nodetool always reports the last token on the first line of the report. There is nothing to worry about here, this is normal behaviour.

Comment: What I had read was that this behavior simulates a ring where the last token is repeated at the beginning, so that you can quickly see the range for each token assignment. In your example, from `8814750030873335965` to `-7618874366231544036` is the token range handled by your 1st node and so on down the column.